# Can I inject text links within the body of a web-page

Tags: javascript, html, replace, google-chrome-extension, inject

I am coding a proof of concept for my boss, I am a backend developer and haven't done javascript in years so I don't know much about same origin policy and other obstacles.

He basically has a chrome plugin and wants to replace matching keywords with links to his service, this will happen in any domain the user visits and not just one, similar to in-text advertising.

I was also wondering if it's possible to do this with an iframe, without the need of a chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Chrome extention for that and permisions for [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

It takes a lot of improvement but basically what you want to do is this:

```
document.onload = function(){ 

    var textToParse = document.body.innerHTML,
        linkHTML    = '<a href="some.url">Your Boss\'s Service Reference</a>',
        newText     = ''; 

    textToParse.split('Your Boss\'s Service Reference').join(linkHTML);
    document.body.innerHTML = newText;

}
```

**WARNING:** The above code is a basic example of how to do it but might cause problems if the search in `textToParse` matches something that is HTML code. You should use jQuery and other tools for an easier/more secure way to edit text within HTML elements.

Comment: Oh this does wreck much more havok than that. Recreating HTML content with `innerHTML` assignment completely wipes anything attached to HTML elements (like, you know, event handlers..)

Comment: And yet the first part of your answer is right, so I can't bring myself to downvote. Neither upvote, though.

Comment: Does answer the question about being possible so it takes care of the important part related to extensions. Implementation is more of a dom issue.